# How to include empty nodeset in XSLT Muenchian grouping?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform my XML into groups of rows and columns through `<RowBreak>` and `<ColumnBreak>`. I can now successfully transform it using Muenchian grouping, but how do I include the empty nodes? In the example below, there are two `<ColumnBreak />` with empty string in between, so the expected output is:

[image]

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Tree>
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 1</Label>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 2</Label>
  </Item>
  <ColumnBreak /> 
  <ColumnBreak />
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 3</Label>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 4</Label>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 5</Label>
  </Item>
  <RowBreak />
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 6</Label>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 7</Label>
  </Item>
  <ColumnBreak />
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 8</Label>
  </Item>
  <RowBreak />
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 9</Label>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Label>Item 10</Label>
  </Item>
</Tree>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="cell-by-row" match="cell" use="@row" />
  <xsl:key name="cell-by-col" match="cell" use="concat(@row, '|', @col)" />

  <xsl:template match="/Tree">
    <xsl:variable name="cells">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="sibling">
        <xsl:with-param name="row" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="col" select="1"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <table border = "1">
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($cells)/cell[count(. | key('cell-by-row', @row)[1]) = 1]">
        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('cell-by-row', @row)[count(. | key('cell-by-col', concat(@row, '|', @col))[1]) = 1]">
            <td>
              <xsl:for-each select="key('cell-by-col', concat(@row, '|', @col))">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <br/>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="sibling">
    <xsl:param name="row"/>
    <xsl:param name="col"/>
    <cell row="{$row}" col="{$col}">
      <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
    </cell>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sibling">
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ColumnBreak" mode="sibling">
    <xsl:param name="row"/>
    <xsl:param name="col"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sibling">
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="RowBreak" mode="sibling">
    <xsl:param name="row"/>
    <xsl:param name="col"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sibling">
      <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row + 1"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="col" select="1"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How about a **simple** example that concentrates on the problem at hand and eliminates everything else? -- In general, empty nodes can be selected by a key by using `string(node)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fix you can make, without making big changes to your XSLT is to amend your `ColumnBreak` template to check whether the preceding sibling is anything other than an `Item`. In this case, you can add an "empty" cell

```
<xsl:template match="ColumnBreak" mode="sibling">
  <xsl:param name="row"/>
  <xsl:param name="col"/>
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::Item])">
    <cell row="{$row}" col="{$col}" empty="true" />
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]" mode="sibling">
    <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="col" select="$col + 1"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, in your main template, you can check for empty cells

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('cell-by-col', concat(@row, '|', @col))">
  <xsl:if test="not(@empty)">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In fact, you could even omit the check on `@empty` here if you are happy for the empty cell to have a `<br />` tag in.

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP1